# How do I solve a segmentation violation in go?

Tags: go, segmentation-fault

I am writing a spider in go and have the following code so far:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func handleEnd() {
    //handle end (close channels, etc)
    fmt.Println("Placeholder")
}

func worker(c chan string) {
    var url string
    url = <-c
    fmt.Println(url)
    //get the url
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        //we should log this incase this is in the background
    }

    //operate on it
    //find links
    z := html.NewTokenizer(resp.Body)
    for {
        tt := z.Next()

        switch {
        case tt == html.ErrorToken:
            // End of the document, we're done
            return
        case tt == html.StartTagToken:
            t := z.Token()

            isAnchor := t.Data == "a"
            if isAnchor {
                fmt.Println("We found a link!")
            }
        }
    }
    //handle local links()
    //send links to channel
    //}
}

func genStartUrls(howMany, length int) []string {
    var ans []string
    var letters = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 0; i < howMany; i++ {
        b := make([]byte, length)
        for i := range b {
            b[i] = byte(letters[rand.Intn(len(letters))])
        }
        ans = append(ans, "http://"+string(b)+".com")
    }
    return ans
}

func main() {
    defer handleEnd()
    workers := 3
    l := make(chan string, 10000)
    defer close(l)
    for _, url := range genStartUrls(100, 3) {
        l <- url
    }
    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        go worker(l)
    }
    for {
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
}
```

At first, it works as intended (it finds the hrefs from the page), but then when I break it and run it again, then do the same thing a few more times, I get the following error:

```
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x6454f1]

goroutine 7 [running]:
main.worker(0xc0000662a0)
        /home/name/go/src/spider/main.go:25 +0x121
created by main.main
        /home/name/go/src/spider/main.go:85 +0x138
exit status 2
```

When I restart my computer, the problem goes away for a few runs of the program, but then comes back. This makes me think that the goroutines might not be ending when my main program ends, but continuing as zombie processes. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goroutines cannot continue after the program ends.

The below lines are the likely source of your problem:

```
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
```

You have to move the `defer` after the error check, because if there is error, `resp` will be nil, and `defer resp.Body.Close()` will fail.

```
   resp, err := http.Get(url)
   if err != nil {
      ...
      return err
   }
   defer resp.Body.Close()
```